# Probability on uncountable set

Tags: probability

Let $A(x)$ be an event depending on $x\in X$. I would like to understand the difference between
\begin{align}
P(A(x))=1, \text{ for all }x\in X,\label{1}\\
P(A(x)\text{ for all }x\in X)=1.\label{2}
\end{align}
What happens if $X$ is uncountable? How can we derive the second equality from the first one?

Comment: From second equality, you can deduce that $P(A(x))\ge P(A(y) \;\text{for all $y\in X$})=1$ for every fixed $x\in X$.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the following example: $X = [0, 1]$ and $A(x) \equiv y \neq x$ where $y \in \Omega = [0, 1]$ with uniform distribution. Then:

$$P(x \neq y) = P( \{ y \in [0, 1] : y \neq x \} ) = 1 \text{ for all } x \in X$$

but clearly

$$P(x \neq y \text{ for all } x \in X) = 0$$

since every $y \in [0, 1]$ is equal to some $x$, namely: to itself.

In general, we can view $A$ as a subset of $X \times \Omega$ by $A = \{ (x, y) \in X \times \Omega : A(x, y) \text{ is true} \}$. Then

- $P(A(x)) = 1$ for all $x \in X \iff$ for each $x \in X$ the section $A_x = \{ y \in \Omega : (x, y) \in A \}$ has measure $1$.
- $P(A(x) \text{ for all } x \in X) = 1 \iff$ the set $\{ y \in \Omega : A^y = X \}$ has measure $1$, where $A^y = \{ x \in X : (x, y) \in A \}$.

The second condition is stronger, because if every vertical section is almost everything, it doesn't imply that almost every horizontal section is complete.